# Singular Verbs for Groups

Tags: глаголы

I came across a sentence on the language-learning site Duolingo that said

> Много людей в Европе и Америке знает о Петербурге.

Why is `знает` used instead of `знают`?

One suggestion in the comments was that a singular verb is used when a group acts as one entity, but in this case it seems to me as though each *individual* knows about St. Petersburg.

Can someone explain the usage of singular verbs for multiple things/people?